# Stata read date variable from MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, format, stata

I connected Stata via ODBC to a SQL Database.

My problem is Stata reads date variables as Strings. In SQL they have a date format.

How can I import a date variable in SQL as a date in Stata?

Comment: You can import dates as numeric into Stata in any form you like. A very simple example is years. You may well need to convert within Stata, but the problem you raise appears to be partly one of understanding. More crucially, we need concrete examples, code you tried, etc. For example, I know a lot about dates in Stata and have forgotten the little I ever knew about SQL so to reach people like me you need to spell out exactly how SQL holds the kind of dates that interest you.

Comment: I just read the table in with `odbc load, table("data_table")`  In SQL the formate is just date. My main concern is: I read up to 2 billion rows into Stata. I want to save the extra time to convert all the strings back into dates.  Stata shows the date as `%10s`

Comment: As I said I don't know SQL at all, so the SQL means nothing to me, although more importantly it may help others. Also, your question was how do I import dates into Stata, but you also made it clear that you can do it. I think you will find that date conversion in Stata won't lose time that can be gained elsewhere. Are you importing daily dates, dates and times, or something else?

Comment: @user3614882 show how your dates appear in stata .. give us some examples because you will need to use the appropriate format for stata to understand these strings and transform them in stata format.. i had a similar issue to deal with so we might be able to help you if we understand what you're dealing with

Comment: Usually, you have to add a `datestring` option to get Stata to do that. The default behavior is to convert dates on the fly. Can you shows us your `odbc load` statement and how the date format info from SQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can not answer this question without knowing the format of your date.

I had a similar problem. If I assume your date is in

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

format, then you need this code (assuming that v1 is the variable that holds your dates in Stata)

```
 generate v2 = date(v1, "YMD")
format %td v2
```

A way that helped me understand the format to use is to print some dates in Stata to see what they look like in Stata's internal encoding: For example:

```
display date("2013-08-14", "YMD")
display %td date("2013-08-14", "YMD")
```

Now, if you want to convert your data to Stata format because you are getting a type mismatch r(109); error in Stata, execute the following lines of code to get your data in a proper Stata date format:

```
    . gen str new   = string(value, "%10.0g")
    . gen long date = date(new, "YMD") 
    . format date %td
    . drop new
```

Comment: Stata's `date()` function is better understood if (from Stata 13 on) you use the documented synonym `daily()`.  It yields numeric **daily** dates (and **only** numeric daily dates).  Note that `daily(string(value, "%10.0g"), "YMD")` should work fine so long as `value` contains numbers like 20130814. The device of a new variable, generated and then dropped, will perhaps be clearer but is not essential.

Comment: Interesting Nick. I was not aware of the daily() function in Stata. I will check it out. Thanks